# Validity of $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k_n}{l_n} = 0$ if $\frac{k_{n+1}}{k_{n} } < \frac{l_{n+1}}{l_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find limit of this sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ for $a_n = \frac{e^n}{n!}$. Intuitively we can see that answer is zero. I've found proof with the squeeze theorem. However, something came up to my mind. If I define $k_n =e^n$ and $l_n = n!$, and if $$\frac{k_{n+1}}{k_{n}} < \frac{l_{n+1}}{l_{n}} \\\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k_n}{l_n} = 0$$
I thought if the rate of change of denominator is bigger than numerator's, the limit of $a_n = \frac{k_n}{l_n}$ would be zero. I've tried to prove with the definition of sequence limit, but I couldn't go further.
$$\text{for } k_n > 0 \text{ and } l_n > 0\\|\frac{k_n}{l_n} - 0| < \epsilon\\ \frac{k_n}{l_n} < \epsilon$$

In a general sense, is it possible to say something like that? If it is, how can I prove it?

Comment: If $k_n\to 2$ and not increasing and $l_n\to3$ and increasing then $k_n/l_n\to 2/3$ which is not 0.

Comment: Would it still be invalid if I restrict the definition for monotonic sequences?

Comment: still it is possible to find such sequences. For example $k_n=2+1/n$, $l_n=3-1/n$